# Definition of Phase Shifts (Coupled Oscillators)

Tags: coupled-oscillators, phase-velocity

I was wondering if maybe someone could look at this excerpt from a textbook (Attached). It states that “the displacement of the two masses will be in opposite directions (out of phase by pi)” but I thought that the Definition of Phase was:
Phase = theta in the following formula, cos(wt+theta).

However, the two equations in this book excerpt have the exact same expression in parenthesis, and both are nested in the same function, cosine - so how is it that they have different phases? Many thanks[image: See image of book example attached].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-4\cos{(\sqrt{5}t)} = +4\cos{(\sqrt{5}t + \pi)}$$

Comment: That’s interesting and very helpful! But I’m interested to know why this works? If we were to graph both equations (y=4cos(sqrt(5)t) and y=-4cps(sqrt(5)t), we’d find that the negative one was simply reflected over the t axis, yes? So then, why the phase shift of pi? It doesn’t look like a phase shift (as in one has y=0 at origin vs. another one at y=pi)?

Comment: @Yelena being "reflected" is one way to see it, but how about you "shift" the second equation until it exactly overlaps the first: now, see how far you had to shift it in order for this to happen.

Comment: Thanks so much, that is so interesting!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple GIF to complement @garyp's succinct answer:

[image]

I've plotted the two functions $-\cos{(\sqrt{5}t)}$ (blue) and $\cos{(\sqrt{5}t + \phi)}$ (orange), and I've varied $\phi$ between 0 and $2\pi$. As you can see, they start off being exactly exactly reflected, as you'd expect, and now as I tune $\phi$, the orange curve moves "closer" to the blue one until it matches it exactly when $\phi = \pi/2$, as one would expect.

Comment: I was expecting an animation when you mentioned "GIF". Oh well...

Comment: @wyphan It's animated for me! Doesn't it work for you? :'(

Comment: Oh, it works now! Must be my ISP messing around with me again...

Comment: @wyphan Ok it turns out that the GIF I made didn't loop, so you basically see it once and then you don't see it again for a while :P Just made one that loops, so it should be better! :)

Comment: Wow thank you so much - what an awesome animation! What programming did you use to do that?

Comment: @Yelena This was created on [Mathematica.SE], it's a very useful language to learn :) It also allows you to export animations like this quite easily.